# Plot silhouette for each cluster using Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, cluster-analysis

I want to plot the silhouette whereby the concat_omics_df.index matches the labels (i.e., subtypes). My code only produces a single silhouette value and I'm unable to plot.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score

# Extract labels as an array
labels = subtype_labels['subtype'].values

# Calculate the silhouette score for all samples
silhouette_values = silhouette_score(concat_omics_df, subtype_labels)

# Create a figure
fig = go.Figure()

# Add trace for each sample
for i, value in enumerate(silhouette_values):
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[f'Sample {i+1}'], y=[value], marker_color='skyblue' if labels[i] == 0 else 'orange'))

# Add a line representing the overall silhouette score
overall_silhouette = silhouette_score(concat_omics_df, labels)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=['Overall'], y=[overall_silhouette], mode='lines', name='Overall', line=dict(color='red', dash='dash')))

# Update layout
fig.update_layout(title='Silhouette Plot for Subtypes',
                  xaxis_title='Sample',
                  yaxis_title='Silhouette Score',
                  showlegend=True)

# Show the plot
fig.show()
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [570], in <cell line: 5>()
      2 fig = go.Figure()
      4 # Add trace for each sample
----> 5 for i, value in enumerate(silhouette_values):
      6     fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[f'Sample {i+1}'], y=[value], marker_color='skyblue' if labels[i] == 0 else 'orange'))
      8 # Add a line representing the overall silhouette score

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

Desired plot style:
[image]

Input:
`concat_omics_df`

```
pd.DataFrame({'gene_1': {'sample_3': 1.0,
  'sample_24': 0.2769168880109726,
  'sample_9': 0.8476336051124655,
  'sample_8': 0.49885260905321305,
  'sample_10': 0.00015952709680945414,
  'sample_17': 0.27279460696450986,
  'sample_5': 0.5168936220044964,
  'sample_12': 0.8451105774614138,
  'sample_1': 0.3278741815939788},
 'gene_2': {'sample_3': 1.0,
  'sample_24': 0.18508756837237228,
  'sample_9': 0.3587636923498214,
  'sample_8': 0.30927957360401426,
  'sample_10': 0.20884413804480345,
  'sample_17': 0.09314362915422024,
  'sample_5': 0.12614513055724202,
  'sample_12': 0.19876603646974633,
  'sample_1': 0.43865733757032815},
 'gene_3': {'sample_3': 0.9493869925654914,
  'sample_24': 0.31909568662059734,
  'sample_9': 0.5960829592441739,
  'sample_8': 0.9197452632517414,
  'sample_10': 0.7254737691610931,
  'sample_17': 0.8464344154477329,
  'sample_5': 0.3099505974689851,
  'sample_12': 0.6142251810218543,
  'sample_1': 0.1787158742828073},
 'gene_4': {'sample_3': 0.7696267713784664,
  'sample_24': 0.7022702008503343,
  'sample_9': 0.7633376987181584,
  'sample_8': 0.9111863049154145,
  'sample_10': 0.8754352321751506,
  'sample_17': 0.4992398818230355,
  'sample_5': 0.9749214109205464,
  'sample_12': 0.5652879964694317,
  'sample_1': 0.9910274036892863},
 'gene_5': {'sample_3': 0.840021891058572,
  'sample_24': 0.7485833490014048,
  'sample_9': 0.7328929486790542,
  'sample_8': 0.0,
  'sample_10': 0.2554971113552342,
  'sample_17': 0.6611979085394857,
  'sample_5': 0.2501088259705049,
  'sample_12': 0.39054720080817934,
  'sample_1': 0.22764644700817954},
 'gene_6': {'sample_3': 1.0,
  'sample_24': 0.0269706867994085,
  'sample_9': 0.5467244495700448,
  'sample_8': 0.9779605735946423,
  'sample_10': 0.45029102750394195,
  'sample_17': 0.7956796281636271,
  'sample_5': 0.7383701259823617,
  'sample_12': 0.5853584308141041,
  'sample_1': 0.6824036034795679},
 'gene_7': {'sample_3': 0.3717641612000655,
  'sample_24': 0.5250321407158294,
  'sample_9': 0.9799894589704538,
  'sample_8': 0.544258949184075,
  'sample_10': 0.1259574907035304,
  'sample_17': 0.41054622347734504,
  'sample_5': 0.2655683593754903,
  'sample_12': 0.20444982520812793,
  'sample_1': 0.8843169565702099},
 'gene_8': {'sample_3': 0.7056397370873982,
  'sample_24': 0.30881267102934884,
  'sample_9': 0.03569245277955437,
  'sample_8': 0.04689202481349479,
  'sample_10': 0.2658718741294945,
  'sample_17': 0.009515673001541103,
  'sample_5': 0.8812144283469642,
  'sample_12': 0.0752454916809566,
  'sample_1': 0.619182723470481},
 'gene_9': {'sample_3': 0.9599572931852776,
  'sample_24': 0.13065213479363366,
  'sample_9': 0.6661901837757194,
  'sample_8': 0.0,
  'sample_10': 0.041023004817151126,
  'sample_17': 0.1493965537050469,
  'sample_5': 0.7074476702007716,
  'sample_12': 0.5508914936808614,
  'sample_1': 0.8892921524401799}})
```

`subtype_labels`

```
pd.DataFrame({'subtype': {'sample_3': 0,
  'sample_24': 0,
  'sample_9': 0,
  'sample_8': 1,
  'sample_10': 1,
  'sample_17': 1,
  'sample_5': 1,
  'sample_12': 1,
  'sample_1': 1}})
```

Comment: Is the issue in this question not about plotly but about the clustering analysis data?

Comment: The TypeError is caused by the `silhouette_score()` function, which apparently returns a numpy.float64 object instead of (presumably) a list of numpy.float64, but you didn't include that function in your post so we can't reproduce.

Comment: @EricLavault Thanks for the heads up. I used `from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score` and have updated the question.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the doc and it appears that `silhouette_score()` returns the mean silhouette coefficient of all samples, which is fine to use for the "Overall" line trace. However, for the bar traces, to get the silhouette coefficient**s** for each sample you need to use the [`silhouette_samples()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_samples.html#sklearn.metrics.silhouette_samples) function.